# ASP.net c# - Could not load type

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my page I have:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="siteSettings.aspx.cs" Inherits="APack.admin.siteSettings" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My code behind is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace APack.admin
{
    public partial class siteSettings : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

It throws the exception:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'APack.admin.siteSettings'.
```

This was just produced in Visual Studio, right click - > new file.  It just doesn't work :(  Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you built the application?

Comment: I was under the impression that when I run the web page from the server it compiles it for you?

Comment: No idea why it worked but it did :) thanks!  Any explanation?

Comment: A `Web site` project is compiled on the fly. `Web Application` projects are not.

Comment: Can you clarify the step? I've tried with the same skeleton app and built the app, then published it an still getting that error

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found one of the possible solution, click "project name"."properties", then name "Root namespace" to the web application name, such as "YourNamespace", then recompile dll

Comment: Doesn't seemed to have changed anything

Answer (score 0):

I answered your question here: [C# Visual Studio 2010 - 'Could not load type' Parse error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837206/c-sharp-visual-studio-2010-could-not-load-type-parse-error/32498798#32498798)

---

You are missing your assembly reference above the page reference:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="YOURASSEMBLY.NAME, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=YOURPUBLICKEYTOKEN" %>
```