# C# Visual Studio 2010 - 'Could not load type' Parse error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

**Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'TestProject.Default'.**

---

*I have checked every other thread on this issue I can find. As yet, I have not found a solution that applies to my case.*

---

**Source Error:**

```
Line 1:  <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestProject.Default" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Source File: /testarea/default.aspx    Line: 1
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace TestProject
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
```

**Relevant Notes**

- /testarea is the directory on the server where the uncompilable files
  are /testarea/bin contains the compiled files
- Project is compiled (using Build -> Build TestProject)
- Runs fine locally when debugging - problem only occurs when published
  to web
- I don't / can't publishmthrough VS (no front page extensions), so
  copy files across (from PackageTmp folder after using Build ->
  Publish -> File System)
- I put a previous project on the web using the same method with no
  issues.
- In all other threads and references to this issue, namespace
  inaccuracies, lack of having compiled the project, and project
  properties do not seem to apply in this case (I have checked numerous
  times and all appear correct)
- Output path in project properties is \bin, the same as the location
  on the server (/testarea/bin)
- Have tried 'Convert to Web Application' but issue existed before and
  after
- Have tried numerous Build -> Clean, and build again, Clean and then
  Publish. No change.

**Side note**

I'm a PHP developer, so these odd .NET / C# issues that are hard to trace and find the logic to are particularly difficult for me. Any advice re. how to properly debug a VS C# application would be appreciated.

This is my first question here. If I can help make this easier with more info, just ask.

Comment: I'm new here, so forgive the extra comment, but I'm a bit surprised that the 2 attempted answers below have been marked down by someone or more than one, without an alternative given instead. Not saying I'm expecting answers so quickly, just seems unfair on those that tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try this line in **`Line 1`** instead what you have already.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestProject._Default" %>
```

Comment: I tried this, but the parse error seems to be the same, just with the '_Default' instead of 'Default'. 

`Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'TestProject._Default'.` `Source Error: Line 1: <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestProject._Default" %> Line 2: Line 3: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

I also changed the class name in the default.aspx.cs file

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem, with the difference that I wasn't able to compile sometimes, some other times I was able to compile but received the error when the browser opened, not loading the page and stating it could not load the type xxxxyyyy.default
What I had previously done was importing some classes manually (dropped the .cs files to the project title), and it was working fine yesterday at another computer. Now I'm on a different computer and receive this error. One problem at the very beginning was when I imported the classes, they belonged to a different namespace. So at first I decided to change the namespace for all classes to "normalize" the issue. It happened to work for writing code, but at runtime it returned errors. So what I finally did was returning to the original namespace and just include 'using NameOfMyImportedNamespace' on top of the Default.aspx.cs file.
New errors relating namespace showed up again. So I finally solved it by also renaming the previous namespace (original) on file Default.aspx.designer.cs to NameOfMyImportedNamespace and it worked!
However, as today I was receiving this new error, I discovered the namespace on Default.aspx.designer.cs file had been renamed back to its original one. So this time when I renamed it, I payed attention to the red cursor Visual Studio draws behind the word you changed, and there was an option to rename that namespace throughout the whole project itself. So I did it and it finally worked.
I supposed my project name would be renamed also, but it didn't, so I think it could be the appropriate solution to your problem.
By the way, I started writing this code yesterday on VS2010 Ultimate running under Windows 7, and the error happened and was also solved at this other computer I'm using now, running VS2010 Enterprise under Windows XP. So I suppose it shouldn't be a O.S. or VS version issue, because it could be fixed by just renaming the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Your First Line should like

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got an old copy of MyProject.csproj file and replaced it and that fixed it.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your assembly reference above the page reference:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="YOURASSEMBLY.NAME, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=YOURPUBLICKEYTOKEN" %>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try removing .Default from the last part: Inherits="TestProject.Default"%>

Comment: When I do this I am unable to compile / build. I think this is because the default.aspx.designer.cs file does not then contain the class name.

Comment: Why should OP inherit a namespace rather than the proper class? This answer makes no sense.